# Vanishing of integral over hemispheres implies vanishing of function?

Tags: measure-theory, integration

Consider a function $F$ on the half space $\{(x,y,z)|z>0\}$. If $F$ is analytic, it is straightforward to show that

A) The integral of $F$ over the hemisphere $(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 + z^2 = R^2$ vanishes for all $x_0$, $y_0$, and $R$.

implies

B) $F = 0$ everywhere

My question is whether this is known to be true for any continuous function (or under some other less restrictive conditions). If so, is there a simple proof?

Comment: Crossposted at MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/138930/vanishing-of-integral-on-hemispheres-implies-vanishing-of-function